# Unable to load style and execute script Express JS

Tags: javascript, html, express

I have my GET request trying to load an html page in my routes.js file using

```
  app.get('/api/testresult', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/path/myfile.html');
  });
```

Also, in my server.js i have the following

```
const express        = require('express');
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const app            = express();
const path = require('path');

const port = 8000;

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './app/report')));
require('./app/routes')(app, {});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running on ' + port);
});
```

However when i try to do a GET call, it throws the error on the browser console

```
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from
'http://localhost:8000/api/testresult/assets/app.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:2 GET http://localhost:8000/api/testresult/assets/app.js 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8000/api/testresult/assets/app.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

My file structure is

```
MyApp 
app 
 —report 
      —assets 
        —app.css
        —app.js
     —my file.html
 —routes
    —index.js
    —routes.js
node_modules
package.json
server.js
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: So, for this error `GET http://localhost:8000/api/testresult/assets/app.js 404 (Not Found)`, where is `app.js` located in your file system?

Comment: If you're trying to show a file hierarchy, we can't really read it in comments.  Please use the "edit" link to add that info to the end of your question where you can format it appropriately.

Comment: Yea that was tough. Added that in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your directory hierarchy shows `app.js` at `/assets/app.js` from where you pointed your `express.static()` middleware.  So, that's the URL that you would need to use for it to serve that file, but you are apparently using a URL with the path `/api/testresult/assets/app.js`.  Those simply don't match.  That URL would be looking in:

```
app/report/api/testresult/assets/app.js
```

But, that isn't where the file is (thus you get a 404).

You can fix it a couple ways:

1. Change the client side URL to `"/assets/app.js"`.  I'm guessing you may have specified `"assets/app.js"` in your client file.  Because this is a relative URL, the browser would then combine that with the path of your web page to construct the URL your server got a request for `/api/testresult/assets/app.js`.
2. Change the express.static line to include the proper path prefix `app.use('/api/testresult', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './app/report')));`

Comment: Assuming I am trying to render an html file from another location outside of MyApp , how should i make this work ? I got your solution to work when i have the folder inside of MyApp. But i'm unable to get it work from outside.
I tried adding the whole external path to the app.use('path', express.static('path')) and i wont work

Comment: @kandarpgandhi - I do not understand what that comment means.  Perhaps you want to write a new question and show the exact details of what you're trying to ask.  Where a rendered HTML file sits in the file system has nothing to do with how the paths inside the HTML work - they are completely separate things, controlled by how you defined your routes and how you specify URLs in your HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174338/expressjs-for-rendering-content-on-a-get-request @jfriend00

Comment: @kandarpgandhi - I provided an answer there.