# ExpressJS for rendering content on a GET request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have an html page as below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Report</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/app.css"/></head><body>

//Content//

<div id="report"></div><script src="assets/app.js"></script></body></html>
```

This html page lies on below folder with structure

```
report
   --assets
      --app.js
      --app.css
   --myfile.html
```

Now i have my application which is trying to render this html. Below is located in routes.js and the structure is as follows

```
app.use('/Users/report/assets', express.static('/Users/report/assets'));
app.get('/api/testresults/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    res.sendFile('/Users/report/myfile.html');
  });
```

My Application structure is as following

```
MyApp 
app 
 —routes
    —index.js
    —routes.js
node_modules
package.json
server.js
```

What should i add here. I do not want to change the html as i believe it should be able to find the files once i use express.static()
I keep on getting the error app.js not found 404

NOTE : If I change href of my html to

```
/Users/report/assets/app.js
```

and same for css, it works but i do not want that.

Comment: You don't show where the `report` and `report/assets` directory is relative to your application file structure.

Comment: I believe you need a relative path for `express.static`

Comment: Where'd you go?  Multiple people are trying to help, but you are not responding.

Comment: @All. Thanks for the help. The solution works when I give the absolute path instead of the relative path. The issue I was facing was due to a plugin not appending the '/' to the assets when trying to create a report. Go that working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your resources such as `assets/app.css` to be independent of the URL of the page they come from so they can live anywhere in your file system, then stop using relative URLs.  Use absolute URLs to refer to them in your web page such as:

```
/assets/app.css
/assets/app.js
```

Then, you can very easy configure an `express.static()` route to handle them for all pages.

```
app.use(express.static("put directory here that contains the assets folder"));
```

Which, I'm inferring from your question would be this:

```
app.use(express.static('/Users/report'));
```

When Express gets a request for `/assets/app.css`, it will check the `express.static()` route handler.  If you've specified the parent directory for your `assets` folder in the `express.static()`, then that route handler will look IN THAT DIRECTORY for `/assets/app.css` which is what you want.

So, in the example above, it would take the request for `/assets/app.css` and combine it with the path specified in `express.static('/Users/report')` and look in:

```
/Users/report/assets/app.css
```

Which would be what you want.

---

When the path you use on the resource in your HTML file does not start with `http://` or with `/`, then the browser considers it to be relative to the URL of the page so the browser takes the path of the web page and preprends it to the URL specified in your HTML.  That really complicates static resources so that is usually not what you want.  Instead, you want to make them absolute paths by making sure they start with a `/`.  Then, they are easy to set up a route for because the route will be the same no matter what the path of the page that contains them is.

Answer (score 1):

You're still trying to refer the path with `/Users/report/assets` where in the html `<script src="assets/app.js"></script>`

Try to change the below code,

```
app.use('/Users/report/assets', express.static('/Users/report/assets'));
```

to

```
app.use('assets', express.static('/Users/report/assets'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have:

```
app.use('/Users/report/assets', express.static('/Users/report/assets'));
```

You should use as path app.js instead of assets/app.js either way with app.css